# Not able to run the `mongodb` server in `mac` machine

Tags: mongodb

I am trying to run the `mongodb` with my mac machine. but turning with error as :

```
02:14:29 /Applications/mongodb-osx-x86_64-3.6.2/bin$ ./mongo test
MongoDB shell version v3.6.2
connecting to: mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/test
2018-01-30T14:14:35.790+0530 W NETWORK  [thread1] Failed to connect to 127.0.0.1:27017, in(checking socket for error after poll), reason: Connection refused
2018-01-30T14:14:35.792+0530 E QUERY    [thread1] Error: couldn't connect to server 127.0.0.1:27017, connection attempt failed :
connect@src/mongo/shell/mongo.js:251:13
@(connect):1:6
exception: connect failed
02:14:35 /Applications/mongodb-osx-x86_64-3.6.2/bin$
```

how to fix this? what is issue with my system?
any one help me?

thanks in advance.

Comment: you have to run `mongod` (the server) before running `mongo` (the shell)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to have a mongodb server running on your machine before you can user `mongo`. Follow this -

- Open a terminal tab and run - `mongod`. This will start the mongodb server.
- Open another terminal/tab and run - `mongo`. This will start the mongo shell and connect to the server

Comment: I have created the db folder like : `03:02:54 /$ cd data
03:03:05 /data$ ls
db
03:03:06 /data$ ` but getting error as `I STORAGE  [initandlisten] exception in initAndListen: IllegalOperation: Attempted to create a lock file on a read-only directory: /data/db, terminating
2018-01-30T15:03:15.771+0530 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] now exiting
2018-01-30T15:03:15.772+0530 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] shutting down with code:100` any help?

Comment: this command helped me: `sudo chown -R $USER /data/db ` very thanks!